# Why do Android API 11,12,13,14 not shown in usage statistic and on Android SDK Manager?

Tags: android, sdk, android-3.0-honeycomb, ice

This might sound a dumb question, but I really wonder and don't know the answer.
I googled, but couldn't find anything worth.

There is usage statistics of Google Play Store: 
http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Does Google still support these API versions?

I'm really surprised about this situation.
Could anybody tell me the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

almost every android phone now has support for 15. Google still supports these, but it is hard to support these old versions a lot of the time, which is why most people don't bother supporting anything below 15. The amount of new people you get is not worth the hours put in trying to support the old versions. this is why most people update to 15 as soon as they get a chance

Comment: people might want to update their versions it is sensible. But I also can't download api >10 and <15 via SDK manager. If I want to build an app supports between these scale do I have to set my minsdkversion to 10? This is the thing I wonder.

Comment: hmm im not quite sure what you mean. Im looking at my sdk manager right now and i have to option to download everything down the API 8

Comment: and this is how my sdk manager looks like except 'obsolete' versions.
http://i60.tinypic.com/2wn2vjp.jpg
I meant this. So other of these api versions are obsolete now? But i didn't read or hear any announcement about this. That is why i asked here.

Comment: oh i see what you mean. i believe you can still download those sdks manually form google and import them, there just not available through the sdk manager. yea support is lacking for older versions but still officially supported.  
see here:  
http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html